# (Java) Trying to format the layout of multiple JTables with other elements in a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jpanel, flowlayout

I've been working on a Pokemon-themed quiz game in Java (modeled after Sporcle, if you're familiar). Pretty much everything works how I want it to, except for the layout of the different components of the program.

I've never been very good with the different layout managers, and I don't know how to get them to do what I need.

Here's what the window looks like right now:

[image: Pokemon Quiz Window Image]

Now, I'll play around with font sizes later, but the tables themselves look exactly how I want them to. The problem is, I want them to be under the text fields and buttons and stuff. Here's the portion of the code where I add all the components to my JPanel:

```
    panel.add(label,FlowLayout.LEFT); //adding the "big question text"
    panel.add(answerfield); //adding the JTextField
    panel.add(correctAnswerTracker); //adding the "x / 151" text
    for(int x = sPanes.length-1; x >=0; x--) //as you keep adding to left, it gets pushed over, so doing it backwards results in the correct order
    panel.add(sPanes[x],FlowLayout.LEFT); 
    //each table is in a scrollPane, and all my scrollPanes are in the array sPanes, so I'm looping through that to add the tables
    panel.add(startStopButton); //button that says "Start"
    panel.add(exit); //button that says "Exit
    panel.add(timer); //the timer
```

As you can see, the statements to add the text field, and correct answer tracker are all written before the add statement for the tables, and yet the tables are at the top. Additionally, there's the issue of my tables in that loop being added in the backwards order, so I had to reverse the direction of the loop iterations to get the tables to appear in the correct order. I've tried using stuff like setLocation and setBounds to get my components more where I want them, but nothing happened. Also, everything just appears in a row below the tables (and I know that's what FlowLayout does), but how would I go about customizing exactly where things appear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap a panel with `BorderLayout` around ones with `FlowLayout`. Put all the content that should be above the tables in a panel and add it with `BorderLayout.NORTH`. Put all the content that should be below the tables in another panel and add it with `BorderLayout.SOUTH`. Then put the tables in their own panel just as your are now, and add it with `BorderLayout.CENTER`.

Answer (score -1):

Either use a `LayoutManager` or `setLayout(null)`. In the latter case, you can move your components around by calling `setBounds` on them. I've been doing that lately too (not using a LayoutManager), it's quite liberating.

Comment: (1-) Don't use a null layout. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers.

Comment: Except when it makes sense to not use a layout manager. All that matters is that stuff works. It's not even hard to understand a null layout at all. Can you not let another opinion stand without downvoting it? That's just evil

Comment: This is NOT one of those situations. There is absolutely no reason to consider a null layout. Again, learn to use Swing properly and you won't even consider a null layout as an answer in this case. `All that matters is that stuff works.` - no, that is not all the matters. Proper design is what matters since it makes code easier to maintain and develop.

Comment: So you say I'd have to make my own LayoutManager instead?

Comment: You know, there are situations where the standard layout managers just don't cut it. You are too dogmatic. Forget what "Swing was designed for" and do what works well. All you need is a componentResized listener.

Comment: Definitely some layout managers are easier to use than others. Nesting panels helps. Using a few common 3rd party layout managers help.  There is nothing wrong with creating a custom layout manager (gives you reusable code). There is a well defined API on how layout management works. So yes the code you would place in a ComponentListener should be moved to a proper layout manager. In any case `there is absolutely no reason to use a null layout for the simple layout problem that was stated in this question`. The simple suggestion to use a BorderLayout solved the problem with less code.